# Linked list pointer issue

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, c++14, singly-linked-list

There are 2 createList functions, one prints out all the elements of the linked list whereas other doesnt why so?

```c++
/*following createList prints out fine */
node* createList(node* root , int a){
    if(root == NULL) root = new node(a);
    else root->next = createList(root->next , a);

    return root;
}

/*following createList prints out only 1st element, why?*/
node* createList(node* root , int a){
    if(root == NULL) root = new node(a);
    else createList(root->next , a);

    return root;
}

void read(node* root){
    if(root==NULL) return;
    else{
        cout << root->data << " ";
        read(root->next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function

```
/*following createList prints out only 1st element, why?*/
node* createList(node* root , int a){
    if(root == NULL) root = new node(a);
    else createList(root->next , a);

    return root;
}
```

its parameter root is a local variable of the function that holds a copy of the value of the argument passed to the function. So changing the copy does not influence on the original argument.

Opposite to the above function in this function

```
/*following createList prints out fine */
node* createList(node* root , int a){
    if(root == NULL) root = new node(a);
    else root->next = createList(root->next , a);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return root;
}
```

there is an assignment of the original argument with the new value.

To make it more clear consider a very simple program

```
#include <iostream>

int f( int x )
{
    x *= 10;

    return x;
}

int main() 
{
    int x = 10;

    std::cout << "Before call of f: " << x << '\n';

    f( x );

    std::cout << "After  call of f: " << x << '\n';

    x = f( x );

    std::cout << "After  call of f: " << x << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Before call of f: 10
After  call of f: 10
After  call of f: 100
```

After the first call of the function `f` the variable `x` in main was not changed because the function deals with a copy of its argument.

After the second call of the function the variable `x` was changed because it was reassigned by the new value.

Comment: @SayanDas I have not understood the question. What is unclear with this function? The data member data is processed by reference through a pointer root->data and the variable sum is also a pointer so it updates the pointed object.

Comment: in that case how come the following code works

void transformTreeUtil(struct Node *root, int *sum) 
{ 
    // Base case 
    if (root == NULL) return; 

    // Recur for right subtree 
    transformTreeUtil(root->right, sum); 

    // Update sum 
    *sum = *sum + root->data; 

    // Store old sum in current node 
    root->data = *sum - root->data; 

    // Recur for left subtree 
    transformTreeUtil(root->left, sum); 
} 


you can refer to this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transform-bst-sum-tree/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be simulated by this example (`int` instead of `node` to simplify):

```
void createList (int *node)
{
    node = new int (2);
}

int main()
{
    int *root= new int (5);
    createList (root);

    return 0;
}
```

Although there is a call by address in funtion `createList` but the value of `root` remains unchanged (5). and that's exactly what happens to you with:

```
createList(root->next , a);
```

PS : ignore the problems of memory leaks ...

Answer (score 0):

```
/*following createList prints out only 1st element, why?*/
node* createList(node* root , int a){
    if(root == NULL) root = new node(a);
    else createList(root->next , a);

    return root;
}
```

This actually creates a new node but misses the linking between the former last node and the new node.

So this is effectively the same as:

```
node *n1 = new node(42);
node *n2 = new node(43);
```

There is no connection between `n1` and `n2` which you need to create with:

```
n1->next = n2;
```

This is done in the working version of your function by assigning `root->next` to the return value of the next call.

Also I would really avoid a recursive function for appending a node to your list  - Calling your function with a huge list might end up in stack overflow